# Difference between Fisher's method and the sum of chi-square test statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test, combining-p-values

I'm learning about combining $p$-values and I have a couple of (somewhat elementary, perhaps) questions. Suppose I have $n$ independent tests, each of these to test its own null hypothesis $H_0 (i)$, $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. Also suppose that, for each of these independent tests, I must calculate a test statistic $T_i \sim \chi_1^2$ (under the null hypothesis). My questions are:

**(1)** What's the main difference between calculating $\sum_{i=1}^n T_i \sim \chi_n^2$ (and then obtaining its $p$-value) and using Fisher's method?

**(2)** Would the global null hypothesis be "We can't reject *any* individual null hypothesis" and the global alternative hypothesis "We can reject *at least one* individual null hypothesis"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisher's method involves converting each $p$-value into a $\chi^2_2$ and then summing them. Since there is a simple formula for doing this he may, given the technology of his time, have preferred this to what you suggest in your first question. There is not a fundamental difference between them though.

The whole problem is quite poorly specified. The null is that all the $p$s are drawn from a uniform distribution on (0, 1). The alternative is either that (a) at least one of them is not (b) none of them is. For more details consult

```
@article{birnbaum54,
   author = {Birnbaum, A},
   title = {Combining independent tests of significance},
   journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
   year = {1954},
   volume = {49},
   pages = {559--574},
   keywords = {meta-analysis, significance values}
}
```

and

```
@misc{cousins08,
   author = {Cousins, R D},
   title = {Annotated bibliography of some papers on combining
      significances or $p$--values},
   year = {2008},
   note = {arXiv:0705.2209},
   keywords = {meta-analysis, significance values}
}
```

Comment: +1, interested readers can also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78596, there are some nice illustrations in that thread. I also mentioned Cousins paper there, I recall it's a decent overview.

Comment: @amoeba I think that must have been where I found Cousin's paper, thanks for the link